# Random walk on a circle of 10 state. What is the expectation of times it hits its starting state after 100 steps.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let's say it move to left state with probability 0.25 and right state 0.25 and stays where it is with probability 0.5. One approach of would be brute-force: enumerate through all its possible paths with 100 steps. But that is not general and does not work for larger total steps. What are some of the standard approaches to this problem?

Edit: it is interesting to see bounds if expectation is hard to get. I thought one way is to bound return times, which is somewhat like gambler ruin problem.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I literally have no clue. This is a random question that just came up so I don't even have any reference.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This answered a different question than what the OP asked.

The generating function for the net number of rightward steps minus leftward steps, weighted by their probabilities, is $(0.5+0.25x+0.25x^{-1})^{100}$. You want the sum of the coefficients of $\dots, x^{-20}, x^{-10}, x^0, x^{10}, x^{20}, \dots$, which can be just expanded out or even calculated more quickly using $10$th roots of unity.

Comment: this calculates the probability that the 100th steps stop at the initial state and not the number of times it walks on the initial state after 100 steps

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying. What is "generating function weighted by probabilities"?

Comment: Upon closer look, I tend to agree with Dubs. Does the author care to explain?

Comment: Whoops, misread the question (which is stated only in the title).

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the move probability and $1-2p$ be the stay probability so $2p+1-p=1$. At time $n$, the probability of hitting state $i$ is $P_i(n)=P_{i-1}(n-1)q+P_i(n-1)p+P_{i+1}(n-1)p$, where the indices are modulo the size of the circle $N$. This gives you a circulent-matrix of equations to solve. You can find a full [solution here](https://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/diffusion7.pdf). It relies on diagonalizing $P=U\Lambda U^*$, and then showing the eigenvalues are $\lambda_m = p\exp(-{2\pi i m/N})+(1-2p)+p\exp(-{2(N-1)\pi i m/N})$. The eigenvectors are less pretty.

This will allow you to find $P_0(n)$, by looking at $[P^n]_{00}$, which I'm not sure if it has a nice explicit form.

Now that you know $P_0(n)$ for all $n$, by linearity of expectation, the expectation of the total number of hits is $\sum_{t=1}^{100}P_0(k)$.

Comment: I would assume we can find $P_0(k)$ by using Greg Martin's generating function method idea also right? It seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

Building off of Greg Martin's answer...

The probability of landing on the start state after $n$ steps is the sum of the coefficients of $x^{10m}$ in the probability generating function $P(x)^n=(\frac12+\frac14x+\frac14x^{-1})^n$, over all $m\in \mathbb Z$. This can be calculated as $\frac1{10}\sum_{k=0}^9 P(\zeta^k)^n$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive tenth root of unity. The expected number of landings on the start is the sum of these probabilities, so
$$
E[\text{# times land on start}]=\sum_{n=1}^{100}\frac1{10}\sum_{k=0}^9 P(\zeta^k)^n=\frac1{10}\sum_{k=0}^9\frac{P(\zeta^k)-P(\zeta^k)^{101}}{1-P(\zeta^k)}
$$

Comment: I'm glad there's a nicer way of doing this without matrix factorization, like I did. Looks like this can further simplify as $P(\zeta^k)$ is itself the power of a geometric sum.